# Microsoft Band SDK to extract the Goals (custom or default set) from Band?

Tags: microsoft-band

Does SDK give option to extract the Goals (custom or default set) from Band ?
As of now I see sensor data available , but I don't see other details like goals or sleep pattern KPIs etc.,

Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

No, that information is not exposed by the Microsoft Band SDK. You can add feature requests for future Microsoft Band SDK versions at: http://microsofthealth.uservoice.com/

Comment: Thanks Mark , would do that. 
Just to add , I see they don't expose the other vital information like calories burnt , All sleep details etc., 
Is it really the case of just exposing the core sensor data through SDK and everything else is packaged in Microsoft Health app.
Or do we have any automated/programatic way (other than manually exporting) to access these metrics from Health app or web dashboard ?

Comment: At the moment there is no public API to retrieve users' historical data from the Microsoft Health service.